# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas

Tags: python, ubuntu, apple-m1, ubuntu-20.04, parallels

[enter link description here](https://github.com/vinzinz1396/errore)I'm trying to install pandas 0.25.1 in python3.6 (ubuntu 20.04) on a vm on parallels MacBook m1 pro, but I have this error:

```
   gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I./pandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -Wno-unused-function\
In file included from pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.h:25,\
                 from pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c:37:\
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/datetime.h:200:25: warning: \'91PyDateTimeAPI\'92 defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]\
  200 | static PyDateTime_CAPI *PyDateTimeAPI = NULL;\
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.o -Wno-unused-function\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I./pandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.o -Wno-unused-function\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I./pandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.o -Wno-unused-function\
In file included from pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:24:\
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/datetime.h:200:25: warning: \'91PyDateTimeAPI\'92 defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]\
  200 | static PyDateTime_CAPI *PyDateTimeAPI = NULL;\
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I./pandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs -Ipandas/_libs/tslibs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -Wno-unused-function\
In file included from pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.h:25,\
                 from pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c:37:\
/usr/local/include/python3.6m/datetime.h:200:25: warning: \'91PyDateTimeAPI\'92 defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]\
  200 | static PyDateTime_CAPI *PyDateTimeAPI = NULL;\
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.testing' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/testing.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/testing.o -Wno-unused-function\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/testing.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/testing.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.window' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs -I./pandas/_libs -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/window.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/window.o -Wno-unused-function\
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/window.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/window.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.writers' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/writers.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/writers.o -Wno-unused-function\
pandas/_libs/writers.c: In function \'91__pyx_pw_6pandas_5_libs_7writers_1write_csv_rows\'92:\
pandas/_libs/writers.c:3648:15: warning: \'91__pyx_v_j\'92 may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]\
 3648 |     __pyx_t_1 = (__pyx_v_j + 1);\
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\
pandas/_libs/writers.c:3121:14: note: \'91__pyx_v_j\'92 was declared here\
 3121 |   Py_ssize_t __pyx_v_j;\
      |              ^~~~~~~~~\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/writers.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/writers.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas.io.sas._sas' extension\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/sas/sas.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/sas.o -Wno-unused-function\
pandas/io/sas/sas.c: In function \'91__pyx_f_6pandas_2io_3sas_4_sas_rdc_decompress\'92:\
pandas/io/sas/sas.c:3854:65: warning: \'91__pyx_v_ctrl_bits\'92 may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]\
 3854 |     __pyx_t_8 = (((__pyx_v_ctrl_bits & __pyx_v_ctrl_mask) == 0) != 0);\
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~\
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/sas.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/sas/_sas.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas.io.msgpack._packer' extension\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/msgpack -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.o -Wno-unused-function\
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_packer.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas.io.msgpack._unpacker' extension\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/msgpack -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.o -Wno-unused-function\
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.o -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/io/msgpack/_unpacker.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so\
building 'pandas._libs.json' extension\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python\
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function\
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function\
pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c: In function \'91initObjToJSON\'92:\
pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:181:12: error: \'91NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL\'92 undeclared (first use in this function)\
  181 |     return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;\
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\
pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:181:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in\
pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:182:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]\
  182 | \}\
      | ^\
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1\
----------------------------------------\
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qfln1wsg/pandas_d9a8678992bd4c9abaccd19db522713a/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qfln1wsg/pandas_d9a8678992bd4c9abaccd19db522713a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-w73_gplr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/parallels/.local/include/python3.6m/pandas Check the logs for full command output.\

gcc is already installed. Python-dev is already installed. I posted last 200 lines of error.

What is the problem?

Comment: You didn't include the cause of the error, it would be further above in the output.

Comment: I don't know why I can include the cause of the error, because is too long. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The error exceeds the 30k characters (the stackoverflow question limit)?

Comment: yes. it's about 200k characters. Now I include the last part of the error

Comment: The relevant part is going to be output of `gcc`. Most likely regarding a missing a C development library.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how can link all code.

Comment: @jordanm Can I send your error in other ways?

Comment: Post the last 200 or so lines.

Comment: @jordanm I've done it

Comment: I posted the error file.